# Phonegap / Cordova function in Angular factory

Tags: angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to wrap the PushPlugin in a Angular factory, based on [devgirls post](http://devgirl.org/2013/06/10/quick-start-guide-phonegap-and-angularjs/), but so far without success.

```
angular.module('phonegap', [])
  .factory('phonegapReady', function ($rootScope, $q) {
    var loadingDeferred = $q.defer();

    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
      $rootScope.$apply(loadingDeferred.resolve);
    });

    return function phonegapReady() {
      return loadingDeferred.promise;
    };
  })
  .factory('push', function ($rootScope, phonegapReady) {
    return {
      registerPush: phonegapReady().then(function (onSuccess, onError) {    

        // stripped handlers

        if (device.platform === 'android' || device.platform === 'Android') {
          pushNotification.register(
            function () {
              var that = this,
                args = arguments;

              if (onSuccess) {
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                  onSuccess.apply(that, args);
                });
              }
            },
            function () {
              var that = this,
                args = {
                  'senderID': '123',
                  'ecb': 'onNotificationGCM'
                };

              if (onError) {
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                  onError.apply(that, args);
                });
              }
            }
          );
        } else {
          pushNotification.register(
            function () {
              var that = this,
                args = arguments;

              if (onSuccess) {
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                  onSuccess.apply(that, args);
                });
              }
            },
            function () {
              var that = this,
                args = {
                  'badge': 'true',
                  'sound': 'true',
                  'alert': 'true',
                  'ecb': 'onNotificationAPN'
                };

              if (onError) {
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                  onError.apply(that, args);
                });
              }
            }
          );
        }
      })
    };
  });
```

Getting an error:

```
TypeError: '[object Object]' is not a function (evaluating 'e.registerPush(function(a){console.log("fun"),console.log(a)})')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a you call `then` on a promise, it returns the promise so you can chain the callbacks.

I think wrapping `registerPush` with a function would work, like:

```
registerPush: function(onSuccess, onError) {
    phonegapReady().then(function () {   
        // Do something with closured onSuccess and onError
    });
},..
```